# How to live stream webcam audio and video together using a UDP port?

Tags: c#, .net, c++

I am developing an application in C# which will be able to capture audio and video from a webcam and MIC, then stream them together. I searched the internet and found out how to grab the webcam and audio using DirectShow.net. Now I can save them to a hard drive as an .avi file. How can I stream them together and reproduce them on another PC?

It's almost like P2P audio video chatting, so I think that I must to stream them using a specified UDP/TCP port. As a newbie I'm really confused what to do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try MPEG TS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure if I understand your problem correctly. I would recommend reading up on [DirectShow filter graphs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd407188%28VS.85%29.aspx). Basically you have to implement a filter that does not transform the data, but sends it over the network. If you use unicast/multicast for that depends on your usecase. I do not have enough experience with that stuff to offer more specific advice, but hopefully this points you in the right direction